# How to create a number combination from letters in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've been having issues with attempting to output a number from a combination of letter I have set up, for example if the cells `A1:A10` contain the letters `A - J`, and the cells `B1:B10` contain the numbers `1 - 10`, I want to be able to create a number from a combination of letters.

As an example, `ADJ` would become `1410`, `AAAA` would become `1111` and so on. I've tried a few functions but to be honest I don't know enough about excel to even know what to search for, hard to articulate it concisely into any search engines.

Any help or a nudge in the right direction would be appreciated, cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had your text in `CELL` `E1`, you could use the below formula to create the number combination:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B1:B10,MATCH(MID(E1,1,1),A1:A10,0),1),"")&IFERROR(INDEX(B1:B10,MATCH(MID(E1,2,1),A1:A10,0),1),"")&IFERROR(INDEX(B1:B10,MATCH(MID(E1,3,1),A1:A10,0),1),"")&IFERROR(INDEX(B1:B10,MATCH(MID(E1,4,1),A1:A10,0),1),"")&IFERROR(INDEX(B1:B10,MATCH(MID(E1,5,1),A1:A10,0),1),"")&IFERROR(INDEX(B1:B10,MATCH(MID(E1,6,1),A1:A10,0),1),"")&IFERROR(INDEX(B1:B10,MATCH(MID(E1,7,1),A1:A10,0),1),"")&IFERROR(INDEX(B1:B10,MATCH(MID(E1,8,1),A1:A10,0),1),"")
```

This is basically a repetition of the below:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B1:B10,MATCH(MID(E1,1,1),A1:A10,0),1),"")
```

However the start part of the `MID` part increments:

```
MID(E1,1,1)
```

This will work to a maximum length in `CELL` `E1` of 8 character.

Comment: Nice one mate, this did what I was wanting, there was no chance in hell I woulda figured that one out.